# Python Pandas Concat Error (Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects)

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, parsing

I am trying to parse rows of xml from a snowflake database.  The xml is stored in fields of a snowflake database.  In each row of xml, there are thousands of children which I am trying to parse into a single dataframe with thousands of columns.  Additionally, the structure of each row of xml could potentially be different.

I've been at this for a couple weeks now and I've scoured stackoverflow to learn more about this error to no avail.  I'm a python/programming noob, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Error returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/racerx/Documents/Python Scripts/snowflaketest3", line 87, in <module>
    df_cleaned = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 360, in concat
    return op.get_result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 591, in get_result
    indexers[ax] = obj_labels.get_indexer(new_labels)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3729, in get_indexer
    raise InvalidIndexError(self._requires_unique_msg)
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Here is what I've been able to come up with so far.  What I don't understand is that the code works for a small number of rows (<25), but if I do anything more than that it throws the above.

```
#loop through dataframe from sql query
for index in range(len(df)):

#assign root for 
    root = ET.fromstring(df.iloc[index]['RESPONSEXML'])

#store metadata for each row of query
    applicationid = df.iloc[index]['APPLICATIONID']
    createdon = df.iloc[index]['CREATEDON']
    applicationstatus = df.iloc[index]['APPLICATIONSTATUS']
    index = df.iloc[index]['index']

    data = []
    cols = []
    df_parsed = pd.DataFrame()

#loop through entire responsexml tree and 
    for child in root.iter():
        data.append(child.text)
        cols.append(child.tag)

#create dataframe and parse xml into correct format
    df_parsed = pd.DataFrame(data).T
    df_parsed.columns = cols
    df_parsed.insert(0,'index',index)
    df_parsed.insert(1,'APPLICATIONID',applicationid)
    df_parsed.insert(2,'CREATEDON',createdon)
    df_parsed.insert(3,'APPLICATIONSTATUS',applicationstatus)
    df_parsed.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)

#append parsed dataframe to list
    df_list.append(df_parsed)


#populate cleaned dataframe with full list of parsed dataframe objects 
df_cleaned = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was how I was building the df_parsed dataframe. Instead I build the parsed dataframe by looping through the xml and storing the tags and texts in a dict, then using the dict to build the dataframe.

```
df_dict = {}

#loop through entire responsexml (element object) and extract all child tags and texts into dictionary
    for child in root.iter():
        df_dict[child.tag] = child.text

#create dataframe and parse xml into correct dataframe format
    df_parsed = pd.DataFrame(df_dict, index=[0])
```